# Does $\langle h,g\rangle_K<\infty$, where $h \in H(K)$ and $g\in L^2[0,T]$?

Tags: reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

It is well known that the reproducing kernel hilber space (RKHS) with reproducing kernel K can be characterized as
$$ H(K) = \left\{f: f \in L^2[0,T], \|f\|_K^2=\langle f,f\rangle_K<\infty\right\} $$
where
$$\langle f,f\rangle_K = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\langle f,\phi_j\rangle^2/\lambda_j$$
and where $\lambda_j,\phi_j$ are eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of the kernel $K$.

Let $h \in H(K)$ and $g \in L^2[0,T]$, my question is does
$$ \langle h,g\rangle_K = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\langle h,\phi_\rangle\langle g,\phi_j\rangle/\lambda_j <\infty $$

My initial guess is that $<h,g>_K$ is bounded. Here are my reasonings:

Since $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\langle h,\phi_j\rangle^2/\lambda_j<\infty$, then for each $j$, one must have $\langle h,\phi_j\rangle^2<\infty$, and one could find a lower bound $w$ of the set $\{\langle h,\phi_j\rangle^2>0\}$ such that
$$ \sqrt{w} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |\langle h,\phi_j\rangle|/\lambda_j < \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\langle h,\phi_j\rangle^2/\lambda_j<\infty $$
which leads to
$$ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |\langle h,\phi_j\rangle|/\lambda_j <B<\infty$$
Thus,
$$\langle h,g\rangle_K \leq M \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\langle g,\phi_j\rangle $$
Similarily, since $$ \|g\|_{L^2}^2 = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \langle g,\phi_j\rangle^2<\infty$$
one has
$$ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |\langle g,\phi_j\rangle|<\infty$$
Putting these inequalies,one concludes
$$\langle h,g\rangle_K<\infty$$.

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle`, not `<` and `>`. The latter are operators, so there is extra spacing on both sides. The former are delimiters, so the spacing is correct.

Comment: @lz10086lz I think your lower bound $w$ on the set $\{ \langle h, \phi_j \rangle > 0 \}$ can be zero. Thus this proof is not universally correct.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin Thanks for helping with the format.

Comment: @Grandes Jorasses, Yes, I think you are right. Thanks for the help.